# Use Case involving Stack Views, Table Views & Scroll Views in Swift 2/Xcode7

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

I have recently been working with and learning stack views, table views and collection views and I have a question about their use cases. Note: I am working in Swift 2 and CocoaTouch.

I've been wondering which one of these methods would be best to create a UI layout similar to Trello's expanding card layout.

[image: Trello Screen Zoomed Out]

Would this be a series of stack views inside of stack views, where the stack views inside the (Green) cards would be inside scroll views so the stack views inside could extend beyond the screen length? Would this method still best allow for adding of new rows and more (grey) cards?

[image: Layout of nested stack views]

Or Would this be better done with a stack view of green cards each with a table view inside? Would the table view allow for more flexibility or functionality?

My question is which one of these methods (or another method) would you choose to implement this design and what benefits and disadvantages would you anticipate in your chosen solution?